# What is observation_n in universe exactally?

Tags: openai-gym, openai-universe

I'm playing around with OpenAI's Universe module and am having trouble understanding what the `observation_n` is exactly and how it works. On their website it just says, "Universe allows an AI agent to use a computer like a human does: by looking at screen pixels..."

I modified some code that was meant for a gym game called "CartPole-v1" and tried applying it to "flashgames.DriftRunners-v0". However I keep getting an index error, so I assume observation_n is not an index.

```
def get_action(self, observation_n):
        turn_angle = observation_n[2]
        action = [('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True), ('KeyEvent', 'ArrowRight', True)] if turn_angle > 0 else [('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)]
        return action


agent = Agent(env)
observation_n = env.reset()
```

I'm getting this error,

```
line 19, in get_action
    turn_angle = observation_n[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Why don't you try just printing it out? If you can see the error message then you probably can see anything you `print()`, too.

Comment: I printed observation_n and it just returned [None]

Comment: Maybe it's `[None]` in the first iteration only? Maybe try outputting an empty action and see multiple values of `observation_n`.

Comment: Ok, this time I got a bunch of arrays: [{'vision': array([[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0],...,[0, 0, 0]],[[0, 0, 0],...,[0, 0, 0]],..., dtype=uint8), 'text': []}]

Comment: The name "vision" make me suspect that they are raw RGB images. The [description page of OpenAI Universe](https://openai.com/blog/universe/) also seem to say so: "The sample code above will start your AI playing the Dusk Drive Flash game. Your AI will be given frames like the above 60 times per second."

Comment: How would I access this exactly? I tried **turn_angle = observation_n['vision'[2][2]]** but just get an error, **turn_angle = observation_n['vision'[2][2]]
IndexError: string index out of range**

Comment: Oh, you don't "access" the turn angle directly from an RGB image. You most likely need to use machine learning to learn to recognize it. If you have no idea how to do that, maybe flashgames.DriftRunners-v0 (or any of the flash game environments) just isn't for you to tackle now.

Comment: Do you know where I can start learning how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195020/discussion-between-imperishable-night-and-daniel-dos-santos).